# How does compiler treat float literals when it is directly assigned to different type?

Tags: c++, floating-point

Recently we've got some floating precision related issues. Specifically:

```
float values[10];
values[0] = 123.45;
values[1] = 567.89;
```

or:

```
float values[10];
values[0] = 123.45f;
values[1] = 567.89f;
```

or:

```
float values[10];
values[0] = float(123.45);
values[1] = float(567.89);
```

Here are questions:

1. Although a literal written in `XX.XX` is in double format, if it is directly assigned to a single lvalue, does it still compiled into a double value in the constant region of a program? Or it is directly converted to 32-bit single at compile time?
2. Does `XX.XXf` and `float(XX.XX)` has same meaning? Or does the latter form actually stores a double constant, and convert it to single precition at run time?

Comment: You say "you've got some floating point issues" and then you dive straight into asking some specifics about `float` vs `double` that make me suspect you're flailing in the wrong direction. I.e. it sounds to me like you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/188592). Please first make absolutely certain you properly understand the issues here: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/224704) As having a solid understanding of these issues would likely be a more practical solution to whatever "FP related issues" you're experiencing.

Comment: Q. What difference would it make to this code if it were stored as a `float` or a `double`? A: none.

Comment: The compiler could store the floating point literal as _text_ and convert it at runtime. Unlikely, but perfectly allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Although a literal written in XX.XX is in double format, if it is
>   directly assigned to a single lvalue, does it still compiled into a
>   double value in the constant region of a program? Or it is directly
>   converted to 32-bit single at compile time?

The double is converted to 32 bits at compile time. How the conversion would happen is largely left to the compiler. Quoting from the standard:

> A prvalue of floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of
>   another floating point type. If the source value can be exactly
>   represented in the destination type, the result of the conversion is
>   that exact representation. If the source value is between two adjacent
>   destination values, the result of the conversion

About your point 2, for constant literals the answer would pretty much depend on the value that is being passed. While `float(xx.xx)` involves conversion from double to float, `xx.xxf` is already a floating point type.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the conversion is done at compile time, unless the result is stored in a `constexpr`.  And `float(xx.xx)` is extremely explicit.

Comment: @BenVoigt removed implicit.
Isn't the op's example of a constexpr.

Comment: I mean the `constexpr` keyword, which does not appear in the question (and only works for initialization, not assignment)